# Page changes not working in JqueryMobile on android using Phonegap Build

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-build

Got a strange one, the app runs fine in the browser, but when on an android device none of the page transitions work. I have checked in logcat and I can see the address changing to include the hashtag however the other page never loads.

I am using multipages so I have like 3-4 jqm pages within 1 html page and depending on button presses it moves to another one. I have tried disabling `ajaxEnabled`, I have tried using javascript to `changePage($("#some-page"));` none of it seems to work.

The crazy thing is it works fine in the browser, I have tried in FF, Chrome, Chrome with Ripple Emulator and there are no problems changing pages via `href="#some-page" data-ajax="false"` or using the `changePage` method, both work fine.

There are also no errors, as I have tried using the Weinre debugger (which rarely tells me of errors) and the adb logcat and both are clear, no problems from what I can tell. (I had to use adb logcat to debug initial JS errors as the Weinre one didnt list them).

I am using:

- JQM 1.4.0 RC 1
- Phonegap build (profile 2.9.0)
- Android 2.3

Anyway I have googled and checked over and everything that has been suggested I have tried... so any new suggestions? :)

I have had a friend try it on his tablet which is running 4.* and it works as expected on his... not sure what that proves...

Comment: It may not be the support for android 2.3. I did some testing on android 2.0 - 3.0 and had some issues with transitions and effects. Are the transitions not working or is it whole ajax request?

Comment: It is not even an ajax request, it is the same html page, it is just an internal page and I have set data-ajax="false" and also have no transition running on loading that page incase that was an issue.

Comment: Thats odd, any way you could provide a sample of the project? It maybe just and issue with JQM 1.4.0RC1, so with that in mind, try replacing it with 1.3.2. Its a bit more tested so if there are any issues, you can rule out Jquery.

Comment: I do have the APK file which refuses to work on 2.3 however I cannot publicly post it so if you can provide an email address I am happy to give you a test version to play with. I am on another project currently however once I am done with that I will try going back to version 1.3.2 and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no one else has answered I could not get to the bottom of the issue, it seems to be something to do with android 2.3 as it works fine in all 4.* versions.

I will relinquish the answer to someone who can give a technical reason as to why it does not work but for the moment I will mark this as complete.

Comment: Nope, ended up dropping jquery mobile and just hand rolling the css as I am using knockoutjs too which does not play nicely with it.